# Unit testing router logic by separating it into its own controller

Tags: node.js, express

I have a route handler as such: `app.use('/authorization', authorization);` which has a router handler defined as

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) {
    handleResponse(err, response, data) {
        // ...
    }

    sessionService.getSession(req, res, req,query.code, handleResponse);
});
```

I'm struggling to find a way to unit test this and as my first solution, I considered removing all of the business logic into a separate controller so that it could be tested independently of the router.

This is a sample implementation of my controller:

```
module.exports = class AuthorizationController {
    constructor(req, res, next) {
        this.req = req;
        this.res = res;
        this.next = next;
    }

    handleResponse(err, response, data) {
        // do things with this.req, this.res and this.next
    }
};
```

From my router, I have been calling it as such:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) {
    sessionService.getSession(req, res, req,query.code, (new AuthorizationController(req, res, next)).handleResponse);
});
```

The controller is successfully initialized (during its construction) but the `this` references inside of the `handleResponse` method are `undefined` once its called.

Is this the correct way of separating out my methods from my router? If so, is there a way to initialize the `req, res and next` properties of my controller so that they persist for the lifetime of the class?

`this` is undefined presumably because of where the class is created vs where the method `handleResponse` is called.

Comment: `this` is undefined because you're passing a reference to the function `handleResponse`.  Try `...(new AuthorizationController(req, res, next)).handleResponse());`

Comment: @JasonWhite That solves the issue with `this`, but now the `err, response` and `data` parameters are `undefined`.

Comment: I understand that those are parameters to `handleResponse` but where are those values coming from?

Comment: @JasonWhite They come from the `sessionService` when invoking the callback method.

Comment: can you add `SessionService` class?